# Opening docx file in Windows Phone 8 webbrowser control

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am loading a URL in webbrowser control of windows phone 8. When I click on the docx file which is available to download from the site, It is not getting downloaded or opened. It just keeps loading. Is there anyway to open docx file in webbrowser control or to download the docx file and open through IE10 browser of WP8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to attach to the `Navigating` event of the WebBrowser ([reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.navigating%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)). In that event, you'll need to look for URLs that you want to handle and then launch them directly, and then cancel the Navigation. Something like this untested code.

```
void web_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e) {
   string url = e.Uri.ToString();
   if (url.EndsWith("docx")) {
      Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(url);
      e.Cancel = true;
      return;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can easily open it via passing the url like this

```
await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("http://www.abundantcode.com/mydoc.docx"));
```

Comment: I am already loading the site thru' webbrowser control. When navigating thru' pages we may come across the docx file which we need to download or open. In that scenario I need solution.